# Running two Node-RED projects simultaneously in the same instance

Tags: iot, node-red

I have two separate Node-RED projects (not to be confused with flows) because I track them in two Git repositories.

It seems that every time I open one project, the other one stops working. Is there any way to run both projects simultaneously? I found [this package](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-multiproject), but I'd prefer to achieve this natively within Node-RED if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Node-RED is a single tenet environment, it can only run a single set of flows or project at a time.

If you want to run multiple projects at a time then you need to run multiple instances of Node-RED.